# List<> doesn't appear to be able to contain more than 500 items

Tags: c#, list

I'm running into an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. The piece of code it pertains to is the following:

```
public static void readPuzzle()
{
    List<int> conversion = new List<int>(factor * factor * factor * factor);
    int count = 0;
    using (StreamReader codeString = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        String line = codeString.ReadToEnd();
        String[] split = line.Split(',');
        foreach (String a in split)
        {
            conversion.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
        }
        for (int panelX = 0; panelX < factor; panelX++)
        {
            for (int panelY = 0; panelY < factor; panelY++)
            {
                values[panelX, panelY] = new int[factor, factor];
                for (int squareX = 0; squareX < factor; squareX++)
                {
                    for (int squareY = 0; squareY < factor; squareY++)
                    {
                        values[panelX, panelY][squareX, squareY] = conversion[count];
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line indicated is:

```
values[panelX, panelY][squareX, squareY] = conversion[count];
```

I believe it is in reference to the index of the `List<>` conversion. The code stops running when count is 500 and the index is `[499]`. I have now set the size of the List manually to 625 (factor = 5) which should be exactly the amount of items in the List. It doesn't seem to make any difference though. I've read other people's questions where they mention Lists of over a million items so I don't understand why I'm having this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the size of `split` to see how many elements you're actually adding to the list.

Comment: Where is values defined? What is it?

Comment: Could it be the file you are reading has only 500 lines? The constructor argument for list does not populate the list, it only reserves room for 625, solely as a speed/memory optimization.

Comment: I agree to MAV, you probably have less than factor^4 elements in you split method, I think that you're missing the **,** on each end of line in your file. So the last element and the first element (of the next line) are in one element of your split restul.

Comment: @Jeroen do you mean `factor*4`? `x^y`, depending on context, either means `x xor y` or `pow(x, y)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see it seems like:

```
foreach (String a in split)
{
    conversion.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
}
```

must be adding only 500 items, then you're trying to access an element beyond that

Comment: Oh my god you are correct! It seems I forgot to put 125 items in the textfile that I was reading. Tried a different file I had prepared and it runs just fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MatthewMcveig: I had a hard time understanding your answer. But it's probably right. It's completely irrelevant what capacity the array is initialized with. It's just an indicative number. It's relevant how many element have effectively been added. And indeed, the array list is too short, not too long.

Comment: @Codo feel free to edit it and make it clearer, my answer was that the block of code was only adding 500 items and later he accessed an element beyond that

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the , on each end of line in your file:

```
String line = codeString.ReadToEnd();
String[] split = line.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (String a in split)
{
    conversion.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
}
```